# If you are on the moon, would you be able to hear your hands clapping if you're not wearing your spacesuits?

Tags: waves, acoustics, atmospheric-science, moon

As I understand it, sound needs a medium to travel and more often than not, the medium is the atmosphere, however sound can also travel through solid objects.
And even we can hear our own voice talking (though less loud) even if we cover our ears since sound travels through our body.

So, in case we are on the moon where the atmosphere is non-existent, would we be able to hear sound (say clapping or walking) due to sound waves being propagated through our own body or is that a stretch?

Comment: It seems very likely you'd hear something i.e. the impact would be transmitted through your arm bones to your inner ear. But without doing the experiment it's hard to say for certain.

Comment: I don't know, but you should think about your body as a mechanical system, the clap of your hand as the "forcing", and the electric signal transmitted through the vibration of the membrane in your hear as the output. My 2 cent guess: everything filtered out by the response of our body

Comment: there is Bone Conduction BC of sound  in addition to the  Air Conduction AC discussed here  https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10237-018-1053-4 an experiment to test this can be carried out on earth, and would be valid on the moon.